how to add a discrete contour level to a set defined by set cntrparam levels increment
I need to add a critical contour level to a set of contour levels defined by the typical  set cntrparam levels increment
I expected I should add set cntrparam levels discrete but this suppresses the previous contour plots, which I don't want. My script is like this (for windows):
reset session

set grid x,y front

set xrange noextend
set yrange noextend

stats "datos0.txt" u 3 nooutput
set zrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]
set dgrid3d 900,900 qnorm 9 
set contour
set view 0,0,1
v = 7; w = 0.1 * int((STATS_max-STATS_min-0.2)*10./(v-1.))

# MODIFICATION: THE NEXT 3 LINES ARE REPLACED BY THE FOLLOWING 11 LINES
#set cntrparam levels incremental STATS_min+0.1,w,STATS_max-0.1
## IF THE FOLLOWING 'IF' SENTENCE IS TRUE, THE PRECEEDING CONTOUR LEVELS ARE ALL REPLACED BY JUST ONE DISCRETE LEVEL 
#if ((((STATS_max-STATS_min-0.2) - int(STATS_max-STATS_min-0.2))/w) >= 0.5) { set cntrparam levels discrete STATS_max-0.1}

# create level string and sort it by value
   set table $Temp
       set samples v
       plot '+' u (STATS_min+0.1+$0*w) w table
   if ((((STATS_max-STATS_min-0.2) - int(STATS_max-STATS_min-0.2))/w) >= 0.5) { plot '+' every ::::0 u (STATS_max-0.1) w table}
  
   set table $Levels
       plot $Temp u 1:0 smooth freq   # sort levels
   unset table
   myLevels = ''
   stats $Levels u (myLevels = myLevels.($0==0?'':', ').strcol(1)) nooutput
   set cntrparam level discrete @myLevels

        set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10   
        set cbrange[STATS_min:STATS_max]
        set cbtics 0.2
        set colorbox vertical user origin 0.93,0.38 size .02,.585

# THESE 3 LINES, THOUGH USELESS, ARE NECESSARY TO AVOID AN 'undefined value' ERROR MESSAGE WHEN EXECUTING THE LAST 3 LINES OF THE SCRIPT 
set table $qq
    splot "datos0.txt"
unset table

set cntrlabel format "{/:Bold %.1f}" font "Times-New Roman, 10" onecolor
  set lmargin
  set origin -0.373,-0.375
 set size 1.735,1.74  #  VALE 1.034 per la umid. e 1.023 per il vento

# Use a coarser grid when generating labels  
# use a dummy definition g = $smallgrid() to force a single execution of a function that resets the grid parameters
function $smallgrid() << EOF
    set dgrid3d 95,95 qnorm 9
EOF

set pm3d explicit
splot "datos0.txt" with pm3d, \
      '' with lines lw 1 lc "black" nosurface, \
      g=$smallgrid() '' with labels pointnumber 1


where the datafile "datos0.txt" is
 0   66  0.2
 0   69  0.3
 0   70  0.3
 0   72  0.7
 0   74  0.1
 0   74.1    0.1
 0   79  0.3
 0   80  0.2
 0   81  0.3
 0.1     61  -0.1
 0.1     70  0.3
 0.1     74  0.7
 0.1     75  0.8
 0.1     75.1    0.3
 0.1     78  0.2
 0.2     73  0.4
 0.2     75  0.5
 0.3     59  0.5
 0.3     74  0.4
 0.3     75  0.1
 0.3     76  0.6
 0.3     78  0.2
 0.4     71  0.3
 0.4     73  0.4
 0.4     74  0.6
 0.5     54  1.1
 0.5     69  0.2
 0.5     76  0.6
 0.5     84  0.3
 0.6     55  0.3
 0.6     67  0.3
 0.6     68  0.4
 0.6     76  0.4
 0.6     77  0.5
 0.6     79  0.2
 0.6     80  0.4
 0.7     68  0.2
 0.7     72  0.1
 0.7     73  0
 0.7     76  0.4
 0.7     76.1    0.4
 0.7     77  0.5
 0.7     77.1    0.3
 0.7     81  0.2
 0.8     46  1
 0.8     54  0.1
 0.8     63  0.5
 0.8     68  0.3
 0.8     73  -0.1
 0.8     74  0.3
 0.8     78  0.3
 0.8     81  0.3
 0.8     82  0.2
 0.9     50  0.8
 0.9     56  0.5
 0.9     60  1.2
 0.9     65  0.3
 0.9     70  0.7
 0.9     74  0.2
 0.9     79  0
 0.9     80  0.2
 0.9     80.1    0.1
 1   69  0.4
 1   76  0.5
 1   81  0.2
 1.1     54  0.3
 1.1     73  0.1
 1.1     76  0.3
 1.1     76.1    0.4
 1.1     81  0.2
 1.2     56  0
 1.2     75  0.3
 1.2     79  0.1
 1.3     68  0.3
 1.3     75  0.3
 1.3     82  0.3
 1.4     46  0.2
 1.4     66  0.7
 1.4     71  0.2
 1.4     78  0
 1.4     81  0.3
 1.4     81.1    0.4
 1.5     45  0.9
 1.5     60  1.3
 1.5     71  0.1
 1.5     76  0.1
 1.5     82  0.2
 1.5     82.1    0.2
 1.5     82.2    0.2
 1.5     84  0.2
 1.6     55  0.9
 1.6     57  1.4
 1.6     71  0
 1.6     81  0.1
 1.6     82  0.1
 1.6     83  0.1
 1.6     84  0.3
 1.7     62  0.3
 1.7     66  1
 1.7     75  0.4
 1.7     76  0.3
 1.7     78  0.3
 1.7     78.1    0.1
 1.7     80  0.1
 1.7     84  0.3
 1.8     56  0.3
 1.8     63  0.3
 1.8     67  0.6
 1.8     69  0.3
 1.8     77  0.1
 1.8     77.1    0.4
 1.8     78  0.3
 1.8     79  0.3
 1.8     84  0.2
 1.9     49  0.2
 1.9     53  0.3
 1.9     53.1    0.3
 1.9     54  0.2
 1.9     79  0.1
 1.9     82  0.3
 1.9     84  0.3
 2   60  1
 2   68  0.2
 2   73  0.5
 2   77  0.2
 2.1     45  1
 2.1     61  0.6
 2.1     66  0.4
 2.1     82  0.1
 2.2     61  0.1
 2.2     64  0.2
 2.3     64  0.5
 2.3     70  0.2
 2.3     76  0.1
 2.4     73  0.1
 2.5     53  0.2
 2.5     68  -0.1
 2.5     74  0.1
 2.5     79  0.1
 2.6     43  0.9
 2.6     65  0.8
 2.6     70  0.1
 2.8     61  0.4
 2.9     61  0.5
 3   54  0.4
 3.1     69  0.2
 3.2     57  0.3
 3.2     67  0.4
 3.5     65  1.1
 3.8     54  0.3
 3.8     60  0.2
 3.9     53  0.6
 3.9     65  0
 4.1     46  0.9
 4.1     48  0.8
 4.2     56  0.8
 4.3     43  1.1
 4.3     45  1.1
 4.6     44  1
 4.7     44  0.7
 4.7     46  0.9
 4.7     52  0.7
 5.5     44  0.9
 6.6     70  -0.5

The output, depending on whether the if statement above is enabled or not, is

or

Unfortunately there's no such a thing like set cntrparam levels add, a bit like set xtics add. With the modification, I get the error message "All points of colorbox value undefined".

What do you want to do with this extra (or conditional) contour line? Simply add it or use some special color, linewidth, dashtype, how to appear in the legend, etc. ? A minimal (non)working script including data and a graph for illustration would be nice. Is it 2D or 3D?

I would like to simply add that 2D contour line, not some special color, linewidth or other. Just to add one more user-defined countour line to a set defined by set cntrparam levels increment. The aim is to have a set of 7 or 8 contour lines that start from STATS_min + 0.1 and end at STATS_max - 0.1 with a step w (see my script above) that is a multiple of 0.1 and it is defined by v = 7; w = 0.1 * int((STATS_max-STATS_min-0.2)*10./(v-1.)): with such a step, the last contour line cannot often get to STATS_max - 0.1, so I have to enforce it with a user-defined additional contour value.

ok, that's important information. So, what I understand now is that the step is a multiple of 0.1. However, STATS_min+0.1 is not and could be any odd value, e.g. like 12.3456? I'm just wondering whether the contour levels should be "nice" values, i.e. multiples of 0.1, as well?

STATS_min and STATS_max are multiple of 0.1 since they come from temperature values of resolution 0.1 degrees. And yes, the contour levels should be "nice" values, i.e. multiples of 0.1

ok, well, I don't have your data and so far I was not able to create a test dataset which satisfies your condition that the distance from the last level to STATS_max-0.1 is larger than 0.5*w. That's why it would be good that you would provide a script and data. What is your data range? Well, I could post a general solution to add some arbitrary extra level, but I don't even know what your input data looks like and if your plot command is splot ... w pm3d or plot ... w image.

@theozh I'll have a look at your solution. Sorry that I couldn't post my simplified script before, but I got a mysterious error message that I didn't get in the whole version and that has made me loose hours

@theozh couldn't succeed incorporating your script into mine (see above). Got the error message "All points of colorbox value undefined"

After close step-by-step verification and minor changes, I've succeeded in adding that conditional contour level even if getting an 'out of bounds' warning message. Sorry that I couldn't do that before but it required a not small investment of time.

In principle, your question is clear, but in order to give an optimal answer a few details are missing (script, input data, plot type, context, etc. ...).
So, if I answer in a similar short way, the answer would be: "use macros!".
Well, ... probably not too helpful.
Improved answer: create a string myLevels containing your desired levels and apply it at set cntrparam level discrete @myLevels.
Best is probably a working minimal example, which you can hopefully adapt to your needs. View the following script as a starting point for further optimizations.
Script:
### add conditional contour line
reset session

# create some test data
f(x,y) =(x**2 + 2*y**2)/sqrt(x**2 + 2*y**2)*8
set samples    50
set isosamples 50
set table $Data
    splot '++' u (x):(y):(f(x,y))
unset table

stats $Data u 3 nooutput                    # get min/max values
N  = 7                                      # number of levels
m  = 1                                      # step size multiple of m
L0 = int(STATS_min/m+1)*m                   # lower level
L1 = int(STATS_max/m-1)*m                   # upper level
dL = int((STATS_max-STATS_min-2*m)/(N-1))   # level step

L2 = 35.5   # extra level to be inserted, fix value or from a calculation

# create level string and sort it by value
set table $Temp
    set samples N
    plot '+' u (L0+$0*dL) w table, \
         '+' every ::::0 u (L2) w table
set table $Levels
    plot $Temp u 1:0 smooth freq   # sort levels
unset table
myLevels = ''
stats $Levels u (myLevels = myLevels.($0==0?'':', ').strcol(1)) nooutput

set size ratio -1
set view map
set xrange noextend
set yrange noextend
set contour both
set cntrparam level discrete @myLevels
set palette grey
unset surface
set key out noautotitle

splot $Data u 1:2:3 w l
### end of script

Result:

